# Syntax error when moving sql to another server

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Im trying to import my sql file from one hoster to another, through PHPMyAdmin.
Hosting one (export hoster) has the following specs (i guess these matter?)

```
Database server

Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.6.23-log - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version: 10
User: abonne1q@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Web server

cpsrvd 11.50.0.29
Database client version: libmysql - 5.1.73
PHP extension: mysqli 

phpMyAdmin
Version information: 4.0.10.7, latest stable version: 4.4.13.1
```

Now the new hoster that i am trying to move the sql file to has the following specs

```
Database server

Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.5.31 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version: 10
User: goedkope_refills@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Web server

Apache/2
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: 15d5c781cfcad91193dceae1d2cdd127674ddb3e $
PHP extension: mysqli Documentation
PHP version: 5.5.28

phpMyAdmin

Version information: 4.4.13, latest stable version: 4.4.13.1
```

When I am export the sql from hoster 1 and try to import it into hoster 2 i get a syntax error like below
[image]

I tried so many things and also tried contacting the hoster but no luck. Anyone has a clue?

The SQL query is quite huge, but here is the query that contains the error:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.0.10.7
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Aug 12, 2015 at 09:39 AM
-- Server version: 5.6.23-log
-- PHP Version: 5.4.31

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `abonne1q_fotograafhuren`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `wp_app_geodata`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_app_geodata` (
  `post_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `lat` decimal(10,6) NOT NULL,
  `lng` decimal(10,6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Dumping data for table `wp_app_geodata`
--

INSERT INTO `wp_app_geodata` (`post_id`, `lat`, `lng`) VALUES
(9, '0.000000', '0.000000'),
(126, '52.239338', '6.112210'),
(162, '0.000000', '0.000000'),
(165, '52.239338', '6.112210'),
(168, '0.000000', '0.000000'),
(171, '52.239338', '6.112210'),
(187, '0.000000', '0.000000'),
(191, '52.239338', '6.112210'),
(198, '52.239338', '6.112210'),
(216, '52.239338', '6.112210'),
(254, '52.341252', '4.853872'),
(286, '52.346514', '4.895257'),
(295, '0.000000', '0.000000'),
(314, '52.239338', '6.112210'),
(420, '52.239338', '6.112210'),
(425, '0.000000', '0.000000'),
(437, '0.000000', '0.000000'),
(442, '52.266096', '6.216935'),
(444, '0.000000', '0.000000'),
(446, '0.000000', '0.000000'),
(447, '52.254989', '6.177624'),
(449, '52.254989', '6.177624'),
(452, '0.000000', '0.000000'),
(455, '52.254989', '6.177624'),
(458, '0.000000', '0.000000'),
(459, '0.000000', '0.000000'),
(462, '0.000000', '0.000000'),
(466, '0.000000', '0.000000'),
(499, '0.000000', '0.000000'),
(502, '0.000000', '0.000000'),
(505, '0.000000', '0.000000'),
(507, '0.000000', '0.000000'),
(509, '0.000000', '0.000000'),
(510, '0.000000', '0.000000'),
(511, '0.000000', '0.000000'),
(512, '0.000000', '0.000000'),
(513, '52.254989', '6.177624'),
(514, '0.000000', '0.000000'),
(515, '0.000000', '0.000000'),
(516, '0.000000', '0.000000'),
(517, '52.239338', '6.112210'),
(518, '52.237554', '6.098140'),
(519, '0.000000', '0.000000'),
(522, '0.000000', '0.000000'),
(524, '0.000000', '0.000000'),
(525, '0.000000', '0.000000'),
(542, '0.000000', '0.000000'),
(545, '0.000000', '0.000000'),
(548, '52.239338', '6.112210'),
(551, '0.000000', '0.000000');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `wp_commentmeta`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_commentmeta` (
  `meta_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `comment_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `meta_key` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_value` longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`meta_id`),
  KEY `comment_id` (`comment_id`),
  KEY `meta_key` (`meta_key`(191))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `wp_comments`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_comments` (
  `comment_ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `comment_post_ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `comment_author` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `comment_author_email` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `comment_author_url` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `comment_author_IP` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `comment_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `comment_date_gmt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `comment_content` text NOT NULL,
  `comment_karma` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `comment_approved` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `comment_agent` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `comment_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `comment_parent` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`comment_ID`),
  KEY `comment_post_ID` (`comment_post_ID`),
  KEY `comment_approved_date_gmt` (`comment_approved`,`comment_date_gmt`),
  KEY `comment_date_gmt` (`comment_date_gmt`),
  KEY `comment_parent` (`comment_parent`),
  KEY `comment_author_email` (`comment_author_email`(10))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `wp_cpk_wpcsv_export_queue`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_cpk_wpcsv_export_queue` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `done` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `msg` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Show the complete query. You move from mysql 5.6 down to 5.5 that can be a problem

Comment: see the edit of my question.

Comment: My new hoster upgraded the server version to: Server version: 5.6.23 but still no luck.

Comment: I can not see any problems in the queries using sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 0):

It seemed to be some bug by phpmyadmin. HeidiSQL did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

I usually remove all the comments when importing MySQL, especially this part:-

```
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
```

This often solves import issues.